# Proccess.destroy() не вызывает Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread());

Tags: java

Есть файл `1.jar`, который запускает файл `2.jar` как `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("path/2.jar");`.

Файл `2.jar` в свою очередь запускает список процессов также через `Runtime.getRuntime().exec();` и держит их.

Когда `1.jar` вызывает `process.destroy()` для `2.jar`, в этот jar через  `Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new ThreadHook())` добавлен класс, который перебирает список запущенных процессов и закрывает их.

Вся проблема в том, что когда закрывается `2.jar` через `process.destroy()`, этот самый `ThreadHook` не вызывается.

```
class OneJar
{
    Process process;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("run 2.jar");
        process.waitFor();
        stop();
    }

    private static void stop()
    {
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                process.destroy();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

```
class TwoJar
{
    private static List<Process> processes = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Process process;
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("run any1.jar");
        processes.add(process);
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("run any2.jar");
        processes.add(process);
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("run any3.jar");
        processes.add(process);
        stop();
    }

    private static void stop()
    {
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                for (Process p : processes)
                {
                    p.destroy();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

`OneJar` - класс из `1.jar`
`TwoJar` - класс из `2.jar`

Подскажите, как решить проблему. Спасибо.

Comment: может стоит для начала запускать инициализацию ThreadHook, а потом уже крашить 2.jar? И да, разве процессы не завершаются без ThreadHook?

Comment: Можете показать код обоих сторон? И под какой операционной системой это происходит?

Comment: Пробуйте сделать смежную логику на Event событии, к примеру: getListnerList().onDestroy(boolean shutdown_hook). И при срабатывании ивента, запускаем ваш хук

Comment: @GenCloud, проблема в том, что ThreadHook как раз и находится в 2.jar, а за этот jar отвечает просто Proccess, который я и останавливаю, то есть 1.jar не знает о классе ThreadHook

Comment: @Roman, код достаточно большой, добавил псевдо в вопрос. В итоге, когда вызывается stop из класса OneJar, stop из класса TwoJar не вызывается. Система Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Под windows это не сработает в принципе. В windows процесс не уведомляется о предстоящем завершении, он просто прибивается (аналог `SIGKILL`), так что он не может выполнить shutdown hook. Можете посмотреть: [реализация](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/f6030acfa5ae/src/windows/classes/java/lang/ProcessImpl.java#l488) `Process.destroyForcibly()` для windows фактически совпадает с `Process.destroy()`. И в [документации к `Process.destroy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#destroy--) вас предупреждают: "принудительно ли завершается процесс, зависит от реализации".

В windows нет концепции сигналов, за исключением весьма ограниченной реализации POSIX, поэтому джаве в общем-то нечего перехватывать. Единственное, есть возможность обработки нажатия `Ctrl + C` в консоли, но это не ваш случай.

Для решения вашей задачи стоит, наверное, наладить какое-то взаимодействие между процессами 1 и 2, например, EOF на стандартном вводе процесса 2 или управление через TCP-сокет.

А код, который вы привели, несколько странный: в процессе 1 `stop()` вызывается уже после того, как процесс 2 завершился (`process.waitFor()`).

Comment: Cпасибо за ответ, буду копать дальше. В приведенном коде, есть неточность, спешил, подразумевается что Proccess запускается в другом потоке и stop() вызывается когда нужно уже другими классами.

Comment: Решил проблему через сокеты, 1.jar создает сервер, 2.jar подключается к нему, когда нужно обновить, закрываю сокет, приложение закрывается.